# Rscript behaving differently when run from commandline and from PHP exec

Tags: php, r, ubuntu, rscript

Hi I'm running an Rscript with PHP exec and it is behaving strangely.......It launches R but throws an error at the following line:-

```
filein = filein[,c("id","bank","trans_date","description","description_2",
                 "description_3","description_4","description_5" ,"type",
                 "debit","credit","statement_balance", "cleared_balance",
                 "debit_int_rate","credit_int_rate","category")]
```

This simple rearranges the columns in a data-set.

It throws the following error:-

Error in

```
[.data.frame`(filein, , c("id", "bank", "trans_date", "description", 
:  undefined columns selected
```

However I run the same script from command-line it runs without any error.

(I'm running the Rscript on a ubuntu 14.04  machine with PHP5......also when I run the same script on a windows machine from PHP it also runs perfectly)

Anybody have any ideas why this is?

Comment: Are you sure that the "_" character does not somehow get read in a different way when you import the dataframe using PHP5? -- check how the columns are named by adding a "print colnames(filein)". I think that it might be a text-parsing problem which alters the name of the columns.

Comment: PHP runs under different rights than Rscript, so it may not have access to the file.

Comment: @LauriK More precisely, *the web server* runs under different rights than *the user* (in other words, if the PHP script is manually run by the user on the console, `php` will run with exactly the same rights as `Rscript`). But the gist is the same.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks! My web server sysadmin career lasted all of two months, so I have some basic knowledge and can debug permission and dependency problems, but I'm far from systematic understanding.

Comment: Agree that it's likely a file permissions issue. Try adding a check when you read in the file to see if it read in anything... if(nrow(dataframe) == 0)stop("dataframe not read in properly")

Comment: Thanks for all of your help....So it wasn't a permissions issue.......the issue was:----the command run from php exec was  ( Rscript Myfile.r  "http://localhost/categorisation/public/1423746975.json"   )                                          However the argument that was received by R was "http://localhost/categorisation/public/1423746975.json2"            For some reason the ubuntu/php combination added a 2 to the end of the argument string....when I stripped the 2 in the R script it ran correctly

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of your help....So it wasn't a permissions issue(I had fixed those previously).......the issue was:----The command passed to commandline by PHP exec was
**sudo /Rscript /home/xin/Documents/ClassificationApp/ClassificationAllInOne.R "http://localhost/categorisation/public/classification/data/1423746975.json"**

However the argument that was received by R was "localhost/categorisation/public/1423746975.json2";

For some reason the Ubuntu/PHP combination added a 2 to the end of the argument string....I added a line in ClassificationAllInOne.R to strip the 2 and it worked perfectly